# Passing a GOAL as argument ? Plus variable number of arguments?

Tags: prolog, arguments, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

In general trying to figure out how to pass goals/functions as arguments.
/Something like the Ruby BLOCK's concept/

In this specific case trying to have variable number of arguments, but call/2 allow only fixed

```
split(Str, Lst) :- split_string(Str, " ", "", Lst).
split(Str, Separator, Lst) :- split_string(Str, Separator, "", Lst).
split(Str, Separator, Pad, Lst) :- split_string(Str, Separator, Pad, Lst).
read_line(Stream,Process,Args) :- read_line_to_string(Stream,Str), call(Process,Str,Args).
```

first case works i.e. split(Str,Lst), but call does not allow variable number of arguments.

```
?- open('facts.txt',read,Str), read_line(Str,split,P), close(Str).
Str = <stream>(0x564fc8884290),
P = ["example", "of.fact", "\"man(socrates).\""].
```

apply/2 seems like what I need, but is depricated

Keep in mind I'm thinking of having other procedures/functions beside split()

How do I do that ?

PS> What if I have even weirder case , where first and last arguments are predermined and I want to fill the argument in between.
Initially I tried:

```
  read_line(Stream,Args?,Lst) :- read_line_to_string(Stream,Str), split(Str, ..., Lst).
```

which as you see would need filling args in between.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `apply/2` is marked as deprecated (in the SWI-Prolog documentation, at least) -- anyway, you could easily implement it using `call/2` with `=../2`.

Another option would be to define read_line like this:

```
read_line(Stream,Process,Arg1)           :- read_line_to_string(Stream,Str), call(Process,Str,Arg1). 
read_line(Stream,Process,Arg1,Arg2)      :- read_line_to_string(Stream,Str), call(Process,Str,Arg1,Arg2).
read_line(Stream,Process,Arg1,Arg2,Arg3) :- read_line_to_string(Stream,Str), call(Process,Str,Arg1,Arg2,Arg3).
% etc., for as many args as  you think are reasonable.
```

Comment: `apply/2` does not type and has higher overheads (list, args are thus passed on global stack) in contrast to`call/2..8`.

Comment: True, but *if* the args are already in a list, then apply/2 makes sense. In the example given here, apply/2 doesn't make sense because the various options can be listed explicitly.

Comment: When the arguments are in a list there is no typing - not even cross referencing.